# UITableView crashes at cellForRowAtIndexPath with error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

One of my ViewControllers has a UITableView inside of it, and it crashes when it loads the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with the following error message: 
[image]

I've placed `NSLog`s in various parts of the function to see where it crashes, but they all log successfully, so I'm a bit confused as to where it's going wrong.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath has begun");
    // parse data for the respective section's items
    NSDictionary *currentSectionDictionary = _matchCenterData[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *top3ArrayForSection = currentSectionDictionary[@"Top 3"];


    // Cell defaults
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MatchCenterCell";
    MatchCenterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        // if no cell could be dequeued create a new one
        cell = [[MatchCenterCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    // if no results for that item
    if (top3ArrayForSection.count-1 < 1) {

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

        NSLog(@"no results for this item");

        return cell;
    }

    // if results for that item found
    else {

        // Load images using background thread to avoid the laggy tableView
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
        NSLog(@"FOUND results for this item");

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try setting an exception breakpoint

Comment: I would suggest you use `[cell.imageView setImage:nil]` rather than `imageNamed:@""`

Comment: Please learn how to debug a crash by reviewing http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: And avoid needless uses of `stringWithFormat:`. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]` should just be: `@""`.

Comment: How is your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: ???